# flame_tiled and/or tiled package gives error when running on web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, tiled, flame

Using flame_tiled plugin to load a tiled map.
Loading a map through the TiledComponent like so:

```
tiledComponent = TiledComponent("new4.tmx", Size(32.0,32.0));
add(tiledComponent);
```

This works well on a mobile.However, when using flutter for web getting the following error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following UnimplementedError was thrown during paint():
UnimplementedError
```

and

```
    The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: GameRenderBox#0eebf:
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=929.0, h=932.0)
  size: Size(929.0, 932.0)
This RenderObject has no descendants.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: UnimplementedError
```

If the 'tiledcomponent' is not added and only some Sprite is rendered that too works on flutter web but not the TiledComponent.
Any solution? Or a workaround?

> Flutter Channel beta, 1.23.0-18.1.pre flame 0.28.0 flame_tiled 0.1.0.
> tiled 0.6.0

Comment: Which versions are you running?

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the versions being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the package don't support web, it uses Flames `SpriteBatch` API, which uses Flutters `canvas.drawAtlas` method and that method isn't implemented on web yet.

Depending on what you want to build, you could try [Bonfire](https://bonfire-engine.github.io/#/tiled_support?id=tiled-map-example), it has its own engine to render a tiled map, and it [supports web](https://rafaelbarbosatec.github.io/bonfire/#/)

Comment: You can also use the tiled package just to parse the file and then use the provided data structure to render the map yourself w/o using SpriteBatch. However, for better performance, you probably want to render into an image and use it as cache.